Reading txt file with missing values until end of row
I have a number of .txt files containing data that are each (636,800) in principle.
np.loadtxt is fine for most of them, but a few trigger a ValueError: Line #X (got Y columns instead of 800).
When inspecting them in excel (don't judge me) the last row of the txt is cut short, and then there is no more data after that. I guess the write was incomplete, but even if I'm correct, it doesn't solve the issues and no, I can't go back and copy these data again.
I've tried np.genfromtxt with filling_values=0, but still get the error Line #X (got Y columns instead of 800). Perhaps because there is no data in column 800 there is no gap defined to fill?
I've tried this:
Reading non-uniform data from file into array with NumPy, from which I can make an array of lists thanks to the top answer, and then tried this How to convert list of numpy arrays into single numpy array?, which didn't work.
I've also tried making a empty numpy array and putting the array of lists into.
Is there a way to load in the data that I have, despite it being incomplete?

You can read these files with regular python (no numpy), remove the last line if it is cut short, and then make an array from the result.

the separator for each row is probably the same (i hope), would pandas.read_csv be an option? (see also this post)

Use a text editor or viewer to inspect text. Excel is more likely to lead you astray (aside from the fact that it's hugely unattractive in its own right).

Can you just open them in notepad and delete the last row? Or add a bunch of commas (or whatever delimiter) so the missing values will be read as empty strings (or some other missing datatype)?

If my input text file looks like
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5

then this code will split each line by delimiter , and pad it with '0' if the line has length less than 5. so that each row ends up with 5 columns.
f = open("...\input1.txt", "r")
lines = [x.replace("\n", "").split(",") for x in f]
lines = [x + ['0']*(5-len(x)) if len(x) < 5 else x for x in lines]
lines

This can then be put into a numpy array or pandas dataframe etc.

The following may be slow, but maybe it's fast enough for your use case.
from numpy import array, nan
from csv import reader

# compute
# N, no. of values in "regular" record, and
# M, max no. of missing values in a short record

lengths = [len(line) for line in reader(open('data.csv'))]
N, M = max(lengths), max(lengths)-min(lengths)

if M:
    # add NaN's at the end of the record
    nans = [nan]*M

    data = numpy.array([
            [float(x) for x in (line+nans)[:N]]
        for line in reader(open('data.csv'))])
else:
    # regular processing
    ...
...

It should be possible to read the data file once, if it is too slow.
